# how to insert the commas in the decimal values and remove extra zeros

Tags: php

In the decimal numbers how to remove the extra zero which are there after the decimals and how to avoid the rounding of numbers.
i have tried the below code

```
$example = "123456";
$exmaple2= "55.369";
$subtotal =  number_format($example, 2, '.', ',');
$subtotal1 =  number_format($exmaple2, 2, '.', ',');
echo $subtotal."<br/>";
echo $subtotal1;
```

getting the output

```
123,456.00
55.37
```

expected output

```
123,456
55.369
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with numbers, remove double quotes at least to distinguish numeric from string. And if you want to dynamically use that variable, validate if its float or numeric.

```
$example = 123456;
$exmaple2= 55.369;
$subtotal =  (is_float($example) == true ? number_format($example, 3, '.', ',') : number_format($example, 0, '.', ','));
$subtotal1 =  (is_float($exmaple2) == true ? number_format($exmaple2, 3, '.', ',') : number_format($exmaple2, 0, '.', ','));
echo $subtotal."<br>";
echo $subtotal1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$example = "123456";
$exmaple2= "55.369";
$subtotal =  number_format($example, 0, '.', ',');
$subtotal1 =  number_format($exmaple2, 3, '.', ',');
echo $subtotal."\n";
echo $subtotal1;
```

Note the **2nd argument** of number_format()

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$example = "123456"+0;
//$example = "55.369"+0;
if (is_float($example)) {    
    $subtotal =  number_format($example, 3, '.', ',')+0;  
  } else { 
    $subtotal =  number_format($example, 0, '.', ',');
  }  


echo $subtotal."<br/>";
```

Comment: it is printing the subtotal value 123 where as i want 123,456 other wise the code is perfect

Comment: dont forget to upvote and accept answer if its helpful :)

Comment: the above code does not work if the number is a string can you please tell me how to check whether the value is float or not if the value is a string not  a number

Comment: just add 0 in your string value. see my edited answer and accept answer if its helpful for u